# Partial template specialization to unroll loops for specific sizes

Tags: c++

I have written a matrix class which can take different sizes. Now I want to unroll loops for specific sizes. How should I do this?

The only way I can seem to get working is a child-class for 2-d. But this I would like to avoid, as it would result in much duplicate code.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T, size_t M, size_t N>
class matrix
{
  matrix<T,M,N>& operator*= (const matrix<T,M,N> &B);
};

template<class T, size_t M, size_t N>
matrix<T,M,N>& matrix<T,M,N>::operator*= (const matrix<T,M,N> &B)
{
  // ...
  return *this;
}

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Now I would like to add an implementation for the case that `M = 2` and `N = 2` where I unroll all loops to gain efficiency.

(I have timed the unroll in a previous implemenation, and it really does seem to make sense, in particular for more complicated operations then featured in this example.)

Comment: Why don't you let your compiler decide when to unroll and when not to?

Comment: @MivVG I have some more involved operations, that for 2-d can be evaluated much more efficiently when written explicitly, as I can use knowledge that the compiler does not have. In this perspective I may have framed my question a bit too simple. Though the problem at hand remains the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delegate `operator*=` to an overloaded function template. E.g.:

```
template<class T, size_t M, size_t N>
class matrix
{
public:
    matrix<T,M,N>& operator*=(const matrix<T,M,N>&);
};

// Generic version.
template<class T, size_t M, size_t N>
void inplace_dot(matrix<T,M,N>& a, matrix<T,M,N> const& b); 

// Overload for 2x2 matrix.
template<class T>
void inplace_dot(matrix<T,2,2>& a, matrix<T,2,2> const& b);

template<class T, size_t M, size_t N>
matrix<T,M,N>& matrix<T,M,N>::operator*=(const matrix<T,M,N>& b)
{
    inplace_dot(*this, b);
    return *this;
}
```